# Python Regular Expression works on MacOS but not Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, regex, github-actions

I am running a Python script on a GitHub action that runs on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

The script splits a Markdown file into several markdown files based on matching level one headers (i.e `# Header {header-anchor}`), so I use

```py
for match in re.finditer("^#\s(.*?)($|\{)", file_contents, flags=re.M)
```

to get the location of each header.

This all works fine on my local machine running OSX 10.15.4 with Python 3.8.7. The regex matches the headers and splits the file accordingly.

However, on the Github Action Ubuntu machine (which I installed Python 3.8 according to https://github.com/actions/setup-python

```yaml
- name: Python Setup
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
    python-version: '3.8'
```

The regex returns no matches and doesn't split the file. I'm not sure why since I would expect the `re` library to work independently of the OS.

Comment: Usually, with regex, it matters if one OS is Windows and another one Mac/*nix, since line break difference comes into play. In your case, it is not clear what is going on, and without a reproducible example, it will be hard to help.

Comment: Here is a sample markdown file: https://github.com/aparande/BerkeleyNotes/blob/gitbook/ee128.md, and the full script is found at https://github.com/aparande/BerkeleyNotes/blob/gitbook/create_book.py. Is that enough to help reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file I was parsing on the ubuntu machine used a different markdown flavor that didn't have level one headers specified by `#`.